# HTML 5 Picture Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to resize picture in HTML5, there are many examples on how to do it, but can't get pass this point. Here is code fragment that is not working for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Picture Test</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>

  <body>            
    <form action="/MyWebsiteLogo/LogoPicture/95" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="picture" method="post">

      <div style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;">
        <input id="input" name="file" onchange="handleFiles()" type="file" value="" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </div>


      <script>

        function handleFiles() {
          var fileList = input.files;
          var file = fileList[0];

          var img = document.createElement("img");
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) { img.src = e.target.result }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);

          var width = img.width;
          var height = img.height;
        }

      </script>

    </form>       
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code and select file Google debugger shows that file was selected, but img and reader are not initialized with selected file (see two screen shots below). What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

[Google debugger screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj8Ur.jpg) 
[Google debugger screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Nnf.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to get the `img.width` and `img.height`, the `img`'s src is not set yet.

You have to set these variables in the `img`'s `onload` event handler.

```js
function handleFiles() {
    var fileList = input.files;
    var file = fileList[0];

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = function(){
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;
      snippet.log('width: '+ width);
      snippet.log('height: '+height);
      }
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) { 
      img.src = e.target.result; 
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<form action="/MyWebsiteLogo/LogoPicture/95" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="picture" method="post">
    <div style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;">
        <input id="input" name="file" onchange="handleFiles()" type="file" value="" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, didn't realize this! Got it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In this code you can now see the preview image. BUT you wanted to **resize** the image. `resize` to what?

```js
function handleFiles() {
    var fileList = input.files;
    var file = fileList[0];

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) { 
      img.onload = function() {
        // This width and height will be correct because until now the image are not get the src
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;  
        alert(width + ',' + height);
      }
      img.src = e.target.result; 
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;
    document.body.appendChild(img); 
}
```

```html
<form action="/MyWebsiteLogo/LogoPicture/95" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="picture" method="post">
    <div style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;">
        <input id="input" name="file" onchange="handleFiles()" type="file" value="" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Chrome debugger]

Comment: I must be looking at this wrong. Yes, I see that selected image is attached to document and displayed. But variables 'width', and 'height' are still 0 in Google debugger as on first picture in original question. I know what to do next to resize. I just don't understand why debugger shows 0 for selected image size, but image is actually selected.

Comment: Your edit is also wrong. It may not work if the image takes more time to load than the time the browsers tries to get its sizes

Comment: That's because in this lines the image's src not yes set. Just after `reader.onload` and `img.src = e.target.result;` the image get the full `src` and then the `width` and the `height are correct. I was updated my answer. @Kaiido You don't need to downvote for this, I was fixed this too.

Comment: I spent almost 3 minutes of my time playing the 7 differences between your code and OP's one to just find that you didn't solved anything... I should probably not tell you that I did, but I did. Your edit is unfortunately still pointing to some problems and still doesn't add any information about what you changed from OP. I still can't remove it... And if you edit your answer for it to be correct, I'm afraid it will just be a copy of mine...